# connect phone to laptop over bluetooth to use internet

Tags: bluetooth, internet

I got a laptop running kubuntu 22.04 LTS, which is connected to a network over wifi. I would like to connect with my phone to my laptop over bluetooth to use the internet. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is pretty straightforward: create a hotspot on the phone. Set a password for that hotspot. Connect to that hotspot from Ubuntu.

It should be usable to browse. Internet radio should work flawlessly. Watching video will depend on the video, your network and internet quality. It will be slow(ish).

Comment: It should be noted that some cellphone carriers require you to enable hotspot sharing through your service contract. From my experience, you don't even need to pay extra — but the ability to share a hotspot is disabled on the phone until you call customer service and have hotspot sharing enabled. And then I think you have to reboot the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work but it is very slow. The reason could be that I am not really a boffin in Linux.
I switched on my mobile-phone via Tethering the Bluetooth connection on.
I plugged in my desktop a Bluetooth dongle (Panda), installed the Bluetooth manager and it connected actually automatically.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1314919)